# Detecting a Crypted executable that is supposed to bypass antivirus

Tags: cryptography, malware

I've seen many Crypters being advertised to bypass antivirus and they work.

The malware crypted by the Crypter evades antivirus detection.

How would you programtically or using a tool reliably detect a Crypted executable?

I'm thinking of `strings` command and other such tools.

Comment: Just saw a good talk on this at B-Sides London. I think she'll be putting the slides online. http://sched.co/75gS

Comment: @Wally It effectively comes down to "how do you detect something which has been carefully designed to be undetectable?" If there was an easy way to detect a crypted executable, reliably, with minimal false positive results from other files (e.g. password safe databases), they wouldn't be used by malware authors, since they'd be easy to detect!

Comment: @Matthew Ant-viruses don't care if a executable is Crypted since they use signature detection. However as a human or a custom program you can check if a sofware is Crypted wether for malware or code obfuscation.

Comment: @Wally Most use a mix of signatures and behavioral detection nowadays, because of the above problem. The only sure way of determining if any data is an executable which unpacks itself in some way is to run it...

Answer (score 1):

With proper encryption, it could be impossible to know that an encrypted file was originally an executable.  Of course, if it gets redistributed in that exact same binary state, antivirus makers could identify a signature to recognize it.

Such a distribution system would require a process to be already present on the client computer to decrypt and run the virus.  If that were the case, it would be feasible to cheat the encryption to use a variable key in a way that the client process knows how to handle, making its detection almost impossible.

Then again, the process that would handle this task would be the real source of the trouble and could potentially be identified by the antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool to detect packed .exes called [PEiD](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEiD) .

As for good-to-know stuff, check out [this reading](https://vision.ece.ucsb.edu/sites/vision.ece.ucsb.edu/files/publications/packed-unpacked-tech-report.pdf) about how to detect packed .exes based on raw binary data.

There are other tools like RDG Packer Detector, but most of them detect specific packers based on signature checking, so practically the same way an anti-virus does.